# How do I interpret the declaration char *x[5]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, declaration

My professor has a bit of code uploaded online, but I'm finding it hard to understand this variable:

```
char * x[5];
```

Does this represent 5 spaces x has for pointers to characters? 
So if I were to say

```
x[0]="Apple";
```

would this be valid?

Comment: `const` would be more appropriate. Don't want to accidentally try to modify a string literal.

Comment: [declare x as array 5 of pointer to char](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+*+x%5B5%5D%3B)

Answer (score 3):

> Does this represent 5 spaces x has for pointers to characters?

Yes.  One way to examine this is to evaluate `sizeof(x)`, `sizeof(x[0])`, and `sizeof(*x[0])`.  On my x64 machine, those evaluate to 40, 8, and 1 -- pointers are 8 bytes long, so `char* x[5]` declares five pointers.

> would `x[0]="Apple";` be valid?

Yes, although it might not do what you expect.  Here, `x[0]` is being set to point to a string literal, and the values of `x[1]` through `x[4]` are undefined.  Note that because `"Apple"` is a string literal, it's read-only; you're not guaranteed to be able to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that what it is, i.e. an array of 5 `char` pointers, and indeed

```
x[0] = "Apple";
```

is valid.

Comment: @serendip nothing to do with compilers, it's a matter of understanding what a string in c is, try `printf("%sz\n", sizeof("Apple"));`, does it print 5?